# With jQuery, How do I handle more than multi-select elements on the page?

Tags: jquery

I have more than one multi-select elements on the page. The issue I have is that when I retrieve selected values for a specific multi-select element I get the selected values from all the multi-select elements on the page.

My code is as follow:

HTML part:

````
```<table class="table" id="LodgeData1" class="LodgeDataTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="all_activities" class="all_activities" multiple="">
                <option value="1" data_ls_adults_price="0">Horseback riding </option>
                <option value="2" data_ls_adults_price="0">Horseback riding</option>
                <option value="3" data_ls_adults_price="0">2h sundowner scenic drive</option>
                <option value="4" data_ls_adults_price="332">Game Drive Re</option>
                <option value="5" data_ls_adults_price="1000.00">Scenic Flight &amp; Dune Boarding 22</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="table" id="LodgeData2" class="LodgeDataTable2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="all_activities" class="all_activities" multiple="">
                <option value="1" data_ls_adults_price="0">Horseback riding </option>
                <option value="2" data_ls_adults_price="0">Horseback riding</option>
                <option value="3" data_ls_adults_price="0">2h sundowner scenic drive</option>
                <option value="4" data_ls_adults_price="332">Game Drive Re</option>
                <option value="5" data_ls_adults_price="1000.00">Scenic Flight &amp; Dune Boarding 22</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>```

jQuery Part: 

```$("body").on("change",".all_activities", function(){
      var table_id = $(this).parents('table').attr('id');
      var arr = [];
      var x=0;
      $('.all_activities > option:selected').each(function(){
        var activity_price = $(this).attr("data_ls_adults_price");
        var activity_name = $(this).text();
        x += parseInt($(this).attr("data_ls_adults_price"));
        var activities = activity_name;
        arr.push(activities);
        console.log(arr);
      });
      var x_activities = "Total Cost: "+x;
      $('#'+table_id).find('.Price_Activities_List').html(arr);
      $('#'+table_id).find('.Price_Activities_Price').html(x_activities);
    });```
````

So, if I choose "Option 1 and 2" under table "#LodgeData2", and option 5 under table "#LodgeData2", "Option 1 and 2" will also display as part of the values under table "#LodgeData2".

How do I retrieve values of the multi-select elements individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.all_activities > option:selected')` is a class selector and selects all elements with specific class (then their options). You may narrow the selection to the event target using `$(event.target)` by passing event to the function like this:

```js
$("body").on("change",".all_activities", function(event){
      var table_id = $(this).parents('table').attr('id');
      var arr = [];
      var x=0;
      $(event.target).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        var activity_price = $(this).attr("data_ls_adults_price");
        var activity_name = $(this).text();
        x += parseInt($(this).attr("data_ls_adults_price"));
        var activities = activity_name;
        arr.push(activities);
        console.log(arr);
      });
      var x_activities = "Total Cost: "+x;
      $('#'+table_id).find('.Price_Activities_List').html(arr);
      $('#'+table_id).find('.Price_Activities_Price').html(x_activities);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="LodgeData1" class="LodgeDataTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="all_activities" class="all_activities" multiple="">
                <option value="1" data_ls_adults_price="0">Horseback riding </option>
                <option value="2" data_ls_adults_price="0">Horseback riding</option>
                <option value="3" data_ls_adults_price="0">2h sundowner scenic drive</option>
                <option value="4" data_ls_adults_price="332">Game Drive Re</option>
                <option value="5" data_ls_adults_price="1000.00">Scenic Flight &amp; Dune Boarding 22</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="table" id="LodgeData2" class="LodgeDataTable2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="all_activities" class="all_activities" multiple="">
                <option value="1" data_ls_adults_price="0">Horseback riding </option>
                <option value="2" data_ls_adults_price="0">Horseback riding</option>
                <option value="3" data_ls_adults_price="0">2h sundowner scenic drive</option>
                <option value="4" data_ls_adults_price="332">Game Drive Re</option>
                <option value="5" data_ls_adults_price="1000.00">Scenic Flight &amp; Dune Boarding 22</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This solutions worked. with the event targeting I could retrieve values from each multi-select element independently. Thank you so much for the prompt solution @ali-sheikhpour.